# Parenthesis around constructor syntax

Tags: c++, constructor

> 12.1/1. Constructors do not have names. A special declarator syntax using an optional sequence of function-specifiers (7.1.2) followed by
>   the constructor’s class name followed by a parameter list is used to
>   declare or define the constructor. In such a declaration, optional
>   parentheses around the constructor class name are ignored.

Reading that text, I wonder what are the parenthesis around constructor names in the following example which are ignored?

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass() {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no optional parentheses in your code snippet.  The following example has *optional parentheses around the constructor class name*, and these parentheses are ignored:

```
class MyClass
{
    (MyClass)();
};

MyClass::MyClass() { }
```

Comment: Any idea why that is allowed? By the way, it seems we can't do `MyClass::(MyClass)() { }`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: C declarator syntax, probably. Did you know you can say `int(i);` instead of `int i;` as well? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow, that's mad :-) I would have thought that `int(i);` would be an expression which constructs an int, initialized with `i`, as in `int j = int(i);`. There are some funny 'ambiguous' parses in C++.

Comment: `(MyClass)();` is not a declaration but an expression. Therefore, the quoted part of 12.1/1 does not apply to this example. For a proper example, see http://ideone.com/IUx47

Comment: @MSalters:  ... Your example is exactly the same as mine, with `MyClass` replaced with `X`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis : Eh, right, my bad. I lost track of which code was yours and which were my variations.